# Redirect file I/O of sub process java

Tags: java

I am opening a new file and trying to write to it inside a sub process in java. I used the process builder to start the sub process. The file is being created but whatever content I want to write to the file is not getting written. Is there a way to solve this? I can redirect stdin, stdout and stderr of sub process but how to redirect the file I/O. I want to do it on java version 1.7

process is started:

```
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < cmdarray.length; i++) {
    params.add(cmdarray[i]);
}

try {
    //java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(params);

    final java.lang.Process process = builder.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

file is created inside the sub process:

```
BufferedWriter br;
try {
    br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("text.txt")));
    br.write("This should be present in the file.");
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: where is the code you have done???

Comment: without a *code snippet* , I don't think a question will be **pretty straight**

Comment: This is a part of my implementation of the map reduce framework where i create a new process on the node which has requested to start a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close()) the `BufferedWriter br`, this is why the `String` is not getting written in the file.

Try this, may help :

```
BufferedWriter br;
try {
    br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("text.txt")));
    br.write("This should be present in the file.");
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```